# mongodb obtaining collection names c#

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-.net-driver

I'm trying to obtain a list of all databases and the associated list of collections for a connection using Mongo C# Driver.

```
foreach (string database in server.GetDatabaseNames())
 {
  var db = client.GetDatabase(database);

  var col = ((MongoDatabase)db).GetCollectionNames();

   //Do something
    }
```

I'm able to obtain the list of databases but not the collection names. It doesn't get past

```
         ((MongoDatabase)db).GetCollectionNames();
```

What am I possibly missing?

Comment: sounds like a db user problem. Have you changed your user or db server?

Comment: what error are you getting?

Comment: @CindyMeister So I 'm actually running this as a windows service to read data from mongodb and dump it into files. So when I try logging the list of collection of names. It does not even create an event or log anything post this line of code.

Comment: @Mate the mongodb is hosted on my localhost. So I haven't changed anything

Comment: why are you casting?

Comment: @CraigWilson It wouldn't let me use the method GetCollectionNames without casting

Comment: @Mate Yes, I did connect with robomongo

Comment: @Mate I tried the same code with mongodb 2.6 and still I have the same problem

Comment: @Mate the driver version is 2.1.1

Comment: @Mate  But I also tried with 2.0.1. But it didn't help

Comment: Ok, method "GetCollectionNames()"  doesn't exists on driver version 2.0.1...  Check  http://api.mongodb.org/csharp/current/html/T_MongoDB_Driver_IMongoDatabase.htm.  Also add a try/catch block and use IMongoDatabase instead of MongoDatabase.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MongoDB version 2.6

mongodb-csharp driver: 2.1.1

Try :

```
//user: root  pwd:pwd dbName:admin
  try
  {
    var client = new MongoClient("mongodb://root:pwd@localhost/admin");
    var db = client.GetDatabase("admin");
    foreach (var item in db.ListCollectionsAsync().Result.ToListAsync<BsonDocument>().Result)
     {
                Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
     }
  } catch (Exception ex)
  {

    throw ex;
  }
```

**Important**: User 'root' must exists in the db

On cmd as admin

```
C:\yourMongoServer\bin>mongo.exe --port 27017
use admin
db.createUser(
  {
    user: "root",
    pwd: "pwd",
    roles: [ { role: "userAdminAnyDatabase", db: "admin" } ]
  }
)
```

Comment: this works:) I just had to use the line "db.ListCollectionsAsync().Result.ToListAsync<BsonDocument>().Result"

Comment: you can just write
 ListCollections().ToList()

Comment: `item.ToString()` gives not only the collection Name but also metadata. @VansFannel's answer is up to date and works correctly.

Comment: why do you catch the exception just to throw it again?

Answer (score 12):

This is how I have solved this problem, because the accepted answer hasn't worked for me.

MongoDb version 3.4.0.
C# Driver version 2.4.3.23.

```
public List<string> GetCollections()
{
    List<string> collections = new List<string>();

    foreach (BsonDocument collection in _database.ListCollectionsAsync().Result.ToListAsync<BsonDocument>().Result)
    {
        string name = collection["name"].AsString;
        collections.Add(name);
    }

    return collections;
}
```

Comment: Better to use non-async_database.ListCollections() instead of using Result.

Answer (score 4):

MongoDB version: 3.4.6,
C# Driver version: 2.4.4

### Working Solution:

```
        using (IAsyncCursor<BsonDocument> dbCursor = client.ListDatabases())
        {
            while (dbCursor.MoveNext())
            {
                foreach (var dbDoc in dbCursor.Current)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("-----{0}-----", dbDoc["name"]);
                    var dbName = dbDoc["name"].ToString();  // list database name
                    using (IAsyncCursor<BsonDocument> collectionCursor = client.GetDatabase(dbName).ListCollections())
                    {
                        while (collectionCursor.MoveNext())
                        {
                            foreach (var collDoc in collectionCursor.Current)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine(collDoc["name"]);  // list collection name
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

In MondoDB C# driver you have async method and "sync" method that return async cursors.
This allow this kind of compact code:

```
List<string> collections = await (new MongoDB.Driver.MongoClient())
                           .GetDatabase("test")
                           .ListCollectionNames()
                           .ToListAsync();
```